# How to use or add subcommand feature with thor?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, thor

I am creating a CLI app using thor. Its going well but now I'm stuck with the sub-command feature.

There ain't anything in its github wiki and googled around, but nothing helpful.

So, can someone show or point me out how to implement the subcommand feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this (file test.rb):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'thor'
require 'thor/group'  # This is required -- it's not a bug, it's a feature!

class Bar < Thor
  desc "baz", "Whatever"
  def baz
    puts "Hello from Bar"
  end
end

class Foo < Thor
  desc "go", "Do something"
  def go
    puts "Hello there!"
  end

  register Bar, :bar, "bar", "Do something else"
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  Foo.start
end
```

This behaves as follows:

```
> test.rb
Tasks:
  test.rb bar          # Do something else
  test.rb go           # Do something
  test.rb help [TASK]  # Describe available tasks or one specific task

> test.rb go
Hello there!
> test.rb bar
Tasks:
  test.rb baz             # Whatever
  test.rb help [COMMAND]  # Describe subcommands or one specific subcommand

> test.rb bar baz
Hello from Bar
> test.rb baz
Could not find task "baz".
>
```

(This mostly works as expected, except the help information for "test.rb bar" isn't quite right, IMHO. I think it should say "test.rb bar baz ...", instead of "test.rb baz ...".)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was helpful. But I'd to implement it another way. There is a subcommand method that did it.

Comment: Example please? I think it'd answer the original poster's question.

Answer (score 4):

Check out: http://whatisthor.com/

From that site (edited a bit to save space and highlight subcommand usage):

```
module GitCLI
  class Remote  ", "Adds a remote named  for the repository at "
    option :t, :banner => ""
    option :m, :banner => ""
    options :f => :boolean, :tags => :boolean, :mirror => :string
    def add(name, url)
      # implement git remote add
    end

    desc "rename  ", "Rename the remote named  to "
    def rename(old, new)
    end
  end

  class Git  [...]", "Download objects and refs from another repository"
    options :all => :boolean, :multiple => :boolean
    option :append, :type => :boolean, :aliases => :a
    def fetch(respository, *refspec)
      # implement git fetch here
    end

    desc "remote SUBCOMMAND ...ARGS", "manage set of tracked repositories"
    subcommand "remote", Remote  ### SUBCOMMAND USED HERE...
  end
end
```

hth...